# Sqrt induces a problem in simplifying

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

We have an expression such as

```
 Sqrt[-2 - d^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2 - 2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + d^2])]
```

[image]

When we use

`FullSimplify[Sqrt[-2 - d^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2 - 2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + d^2])] ]`

The result is nothing simplified.

But when we use

```
FullSimplify[(-2 - d^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2]) (-d^2 - 2 - 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2])]
```

in which we firstly expanded the second expression and after that we multiplied them to each other albeit without the `Sqrt`.

we can see the result is `d^4` and `Sqrt[d^4]` is `d^2`.

How can we directly obtain the the most simplified yield from the first expression i.e.,

```
Sqrt[-2 - d^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2 - 2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + d^2])]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your purported solution isn't correct. For example:

```
Sqrt[-2-d^2+2 Sqrt[1+d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2-2 (1+Sqrt[1+d^2])] /. d->.1
```

> `-0.01 + 0. I`

It helps to add assumptions:

```
FullSimplify[
    Sqrt[-2-d^2+2 Sqrt[1+d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2-2 (1+Sqrt[1+d^2])],
    d ∈ Reals
]
```

> `-d^2`

Comment: @ Carl Woll, thaks, but when I use `Sqrt[-2-d^2+2 Sqrt[1+d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2-2 (1+Sqrt[1+d^2])] /. d->.1` I just see 0.01!!!!!!!! and not what you have seen!!

Comment: And `Sqrt[-2 - d^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2 - 
     2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + d^2])] /. d -> 1/10 // Simplify` evaluates to `-1/100`

Answer (score 4):

In:

```
expr = Sqrt[-2 - d^2 + 2 Sqrt[1 + d^2]] Sqrt[-d^2 - 2 (1 + Sqrt[1 + d^2])];
Assuming[d ∈ Reals, Simplify[expr]]
```

Out:

> ```
> -d^2
> ```

Comment: `Simplify[expr, d \[Element] Reals]` suffices.

Comment: @corey979 I don't know why it doesn't work sometimes, that's why I use Assuming instead.